# train hog out of memory

Tags: c++, opencv

I m using opencv sample train hog, i have like 2200 pos images and around 80000 negative in the function load samples i receive this error

Negative images are being loaded...OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 46080 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file D:\openCv\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (u != 0) in create, file D:\openCv\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 433
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  D:\openCv\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:433: error: (-215) u != 0 in function create

the function where i get this is:

```
void load_images(const String & dirname, vector< Mat > & img_lst, bool showImages = false)
{
    vector< String > files;
    glob(dirname, files);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i)
    {
        Mat img = imread(files[i]); // preia imagine
        if (img.empty())            // treci peste daca este imagine invalida
        {
            cout << files[i] << " is invalid!" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (showImages)
        {
            imshow("image", img);
            waitKey(1);
        }

        if (i == files.size() - 1)
        {
            cout << "jjj"<< i;
        }
        cout << files[i] << endl;

        img_lst.push_back(img);
        if (i == files.size() - 1)
        {
            cout << "has been  pushed";
        }
    }
}
```

how i could change this function to not receive this error thanks :)

Comment: Are you compiling for 64Bit or for 32Bit.
If you are compiling 32 bit try using 64 bit platform.

Comment: Resize your images? How much data are you trying to load in? Monitor with any system monitoring tool to see if you're allocating way more memory than you realize. If you're trying to load in 10,000 images at 10MB each you'll need to have ~10GB of memory or more depending on how they're stored. That might be way beyond the capability of your system.

Comment: @BennoGeels i think is 64 but i dont know where to check, problem is two days ago everything was ok and everything work fine, but now i want to train it twice for the negative files and it doesnt work anymore, in  visual i just receive an error that debbuger crushed an in qt what i posted here, my images are 64 128

Comment: @tadman: Actually, that would be >200GB. (no `.reserve` call on img_list). And that's assuming 10MB uncompressed images. If you have a 10 MB JPEG, it's likely going to be much larger in memory.

Comment: @MSalters Perhaps multiplying the two values rather than guessing would've given me a better answer. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

The chief error I see here is the lack of a `std::vector::reserve` call. You have a pretty decent estimate how many images you will have (ignoring the empty images you skip). Since you don't call `.reserve`, the `vector` will need to use the exponential growth strategy which typically overallocates by a factor of 1.5 or 2.